Is Averaging vectors generally good approach?
I am working on an ecommerce application where I have eaters and restaurants. Suppose that I am able to generate vector for eaters somehow, then can I find vector for restaurant using weighted average of eaters who ordered in last 90 days? I assume so but are there any counter arguments to this approach.
I plan to put these eater and restaurant vectors in vector DB. When an eater opens the application I need to rank these restaurants according to cosine similarity(will use approx NN). Do note that the first step would be retrieval and will be handled by a different system. Only retrieved candidates need to be ranked via similarity vectors

Hi @MohitJain. It very much depends on what you plan to do with the restaurant vector. Can you provide more information about that?

Hi @noe added more context on the use case.

I think you can make your approach just a little more complicated and use Matrix Factorization to create your recommendation nicely without any over-complication. In this method, you perform matrix multiplication on your data, not just an average. I found a nice tutorial about this here.

Does this scale well in production systems? To me it looks like academia focussed model. I may be wrong though

I think so because I've encountered some applications of that many times. Also, this paper about the method (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/5197422) is extremely highly cited.

Hey read up more about this. Matrix factorisation only works well when relationships are linear. To model more complicated relationships deep neural networks are used.
